# getting the content of bold tags or removing them from list item

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup 4 to scrape a web page. I get all the way down to the content I need

```
>>> for t in td: _CAT.append(t.renderContents())
>>> _CAT
[b'THE OLD TESTAMENT', b'SEAN SONG', b'CITY WALK', b'SLOGANEERING', b'ROOM', b'"BOARD"', b'WORLD HISTORY', b'SPIRITED CINEMA', b'TRANSPORTATION', b'FISH, BIRD, OR MAMMAL', b'PRUFROCKIAN PONDERINGS', b'YOU GET AN "A"', b'COMIC BOOKS']
```

Is there anyway to removing the b'' in each item?

I've attempted using

```
>>> name_one = _CAT[0][2:]
>>> name_one
b'E OLD TESTAMENT'
```

but as you can see it removed the first 2 letters from the actual content of the bold tag.

I've also tried using

```
>>> _CAT[0].renderContents()
```

which resulted in an understandable error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'renderContents'
```

How can I get just the content of the bold tags e.g. b'[CONTENT]'?

PROOF OF ANSWER:

```
>>> for s in _CAT: names.append(s.decode('utf-8'))
>>> names
['THE OLD TESTAMENT', 'SEAN SONG', 'CITY WALK', 'SLOGANEERING', 'ROOM', '"BOARD"', 'WORLD HISTORY', 'SPIRITED CINEMA', 'TRANSPORTATION', 'FISH, BIRD, OR MAMMAL', 'PRUFROCKIAN PONDERINGS', 'YOU GET AN "A"', 'COMIC BOOKS']
```

Comment: Related: [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal).

Comment: I'm assuming it is there to represent the text as bold on the webpage, but honestly I'm not sure I've never had this occur with my previous bs4 scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'b' means that your list items are [byte strings](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html). You can to decode each item to `utf-8` with

```
[s.decode('utf-8') for s in _CAT]
```